# How to read the DisplayAttribute.Name property?

Tags: c#

This seems a rather trivial task however I can't see to find how to read the DisplayAttribute.Name property in my code.

I have a class with a property:

```
[Display(Name="A Nice Field")]
public string SomeField{get;set;}
```

In my code I am hitting a road block.

```
        object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);

        foreach (Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is DisplayAttribute)
            {
                // How do I read the attr Name property?
            }
        }
```

Comment: `string name = ((DisplayAttribute)attr).Name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute)(prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault());
```